# Should mapStateToProps update props asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, redux

I'm trying to determine if it's valid to `await` an action call from React when you need to be able to retrieve the value from props immediately. In other words, consider this example:

```
// Import the Redux store directly (this is just to show that the store will update synchronously) 
import store from '../store';
const state = store.getState();

// Where foo is an object created by combineReducers and bar is a property of foo with initial value of 'baz'
console.log(this.props.foo.bar); // Prints 'baz'
console.log(state.foo.bar); // Prints 'baz'

// Now, call the action to set bar to 'new value'
this.props.setBar('new value');

console.log(this.props.foo.bar); // Prints 'baz' (still the old value)
console.log(state.foo.bar); // Prints 'new value' (updated)

// Currently, this function call will fail because it finds the old value of bar. This is the point of needing the value immediately... This function will need to look for the updated value of bar in state. I can't pass the new value directly as a parameter, because the function may also need to be called in other situations where it's not readily available like this one.
doSomethingThatWillLookForBar();
```

This is the behavior I have observed: the action is synchronous and the Redux store is updated synchronously, but the component is updated asynchronously. Watching the debugger, I can see that the prop is correctly updated, so `mapStateToProps` is working, just not synchronously. If so, it would make it just like `setState`. When setting state, if you immediately need to get the updated state, you either need to `await` the `setState` or use `setState`'s callback parameter. So... when I `await` my action call, it works perfectly:

```
// Before action call
console.log(this.props.foo.bar); // Prints 'baz'
console.log(state.foo.bar); // Prints 'baz'

// Now, call the action with an await
await this.props.setBar('new value');

console.log(this.props.foo.bar); // Prints 'new value'  (updated)
console.log(state.foo.bar); // Prints 'new value' (updated)
```

So, this works quite well, but I can't find anything in the documentation to confirm that it's acceptable to do this. Everything I can find suggests that Redux operations should be fully synchronous (unless using Thunk middleware to send an asynchronous action). This leaves me with a suspicion that something is wrong. I'm guessing that my usage is correct and this omission in the documentation is just because the documentation assumes you generally wouldn't need to immediately pull the value you set from props (since you set it, so should already have it on hand). So, just trying to get some confirmation that this is expected behavior before assuming it's correct and moving on.

For reference, this is my use of the `connect` function:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  foo: state.foo
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setBar: (value) => {
      dispatch(setBar(value))
    }
  }
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Foo);
```

Comment: Can you isolate it and create a CodeSandbox to play with, please?

Comment: uhm, why do you use both redux state and component state? is there a specific reason? tell me this and I'll write an answer about it, most likely in detail

Comment: Please show the context of the component you're trying to use this in. It is not clear from what method within the component you would be calling `this.props.setBar`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell `this.props.setBar` could be called from any Component method. I'm referring to any time a dispatchable action is called from within a connected React component and that same method immediately needs to access the value from props.
@Luna I'm not using React state at all here. The `state` is the Redux state from `store.getState()`... this is just to show that the Redux state itself **is** updating synchronously, but the component's props update asynchronously (same behavior as using React's `setState`)

Answer (score 2):

Dispatching actions updates the store immediately.  However, React component props will not be updated immediately afterwards, because:

- You're still in the middle of executing the current event loop, so React has not had a chance to re-render the component yet
- Depending on where and when the action was dispatched, React may render the component asynchronously, not immediately

Comment: Cool... so it's appropriate to use `await` on the action when I need to wait for React to update? Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate on the 2nd point ? any available documentation for this?